# How to prevent an event function from being run twice with multiple event handlers?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site which requires a lot of click events, but I can't for the love of coding figure out how to make it compatible with both desktops and touch devices.

Here is a typical click event, which uses both `click` and `touchend` to cover both desktop and touch devices:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click touchend', function(e) {
  // Some code
});
```

The problem with this though is that it runs twice on touch devices, which is a huge problem. I've tried using `touchstart` and separating with a comma (`'click, touchend'`) as well but with no luck, also haven't been able to find a solution whilst searching the web.

Is this the way to make sure that your click events fire properly? If so, why isn't it working as expected? If not, what would be a more suitable way?

Comment: What fails when you only use "click"?

Comment: Missing `)`, I'd suggest to use something like this, `var event = 'click'; if (touchDeviceSupportingTouchend) { event = 'touchend'; } $('selector').on(event, function() ...`

Comment: @spender The function doesn't get run if using only click on touch devices.

Comment: Click should work fine on both

Comment: @DexTer I've ran multiple tests which shows that it doesn't :/

Comment: @DexTer There is a difference buddy.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I know. But usual clicks should be handled. For other cases, more code/explanation should have been posted.

Comment: @DexTer Agreed, buddy.

Comment: @DexTer How would more code have helped? The problem is the declaration of the handler, not the code inside it. So I just posted an example of a handler.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Just cool. That's fine. Lemme know if my answer helps you.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz-More code would have helped others to understand your use case. Usually we don't add click and touchend for events still they work fine on all devices. Yours doesn't which means something is going on. Community need to understand issue to help properly...

Comment: Dexter has a point too... `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way:

```
var eventH = "";
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)
  eventH = "touchend";
else
  eventH = "click";
// Just taking care of exceptions.
if (eventH != "")
  $('#myBtn').on(eventH, function(e) {
    // Some code
  });
```